# Turn off Windows 10 Task View sliding animation

Tags: windows-10, animation, task-view

I actually use the new task view tool provided in Windows 10 and I was wondering if there is a way to disable the sliding animation between different desktops. I find this kind of annoying and it seems to take a second each time for the animation to play. It would be great if there was a way to disable this so each time I switch to a desktop, it switches instantly instead of playing the animation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Control panel  →  System  →  Advanced system settings  →  Performance settings. 
Uncheck "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing".

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would have to dig a lot deeper to change this, do you know by chance if there's a way to **just** change the sliding animation but not minimizing/maximizing windows?

Comment: ooh it's so much faster without animation. thank you!

Comment: Not sure why, but for me Win10 machine I had also to uncheck the first option to disable Task View sliding animation, an option called "Animate controls and elements inside windows"

Comment: holy crap windows just got fast! although to be fair minimizing animations never hurt anyone ) it's this damn super-slow sliding thing that is so annoying

Comment: In Win 10 version 1803, *Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing* controls desktop sliding, while *Animate controls and elements inside windows* appears to control sliding of the task bar buttons.

Comment: Even with the animation disabled, there still is a filchering, the same as the one at the end of the sliding animation. It looks as if the windows are resized once again (slightly gets bigger, maybe to align them to the grid?). Isn't this a bug? I have noticed this for years, and still no fixes. Such amateurish programming.

Answer (score 0):

Only with OFFICE 2016 products, windows weirdly slid around when they were selected and moved - far delayed behind the mouse movement.  I had to use WINDOWS-U first, to turn off 'Show Animations in Windows' - this deselected several things in the Performance settings dialog mentioned above.  This helped 90%, but the window movement was still slightly delayed behind mouse movement when dragging.  The final change that worked was the Show Window Contents While Dragging getting turned off.  Performance is now snappy like it ought to be (as it IS for ALL other apps on the machine!).  Turned off: Animate controls and elements inside Windows, Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing, Fade or slide menus into view, Fade or slide ToolTips into view, Fade out menu items after clicking, Show window contents while dragging, Slide open combo boxes, and Smooth-scroll list boxes.